# Как в PhpStorm Добавить поиск по wp-kama?

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm

В PhpStorm есть поиск в Google и на WordPress.org. Достаточно выделить нужный фрагмент кода, кликнуть правой кнопкой и во всплывающем меню выбрать нужный тип поиска.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не секрет, что сайт `wp-kama.ru` предоставляет более полную информацию по функциям и хукам WordPress, чем официальный кодекс WoRdPress.org. Более того, содержит информацию на русском языке.

Как добавить поиск по `wp-kama.ru` во всплювающее меню редактора PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для организации такого поиска сначала надо создать external Action в PhpStorm.

Для этого надо зайти в настройки (Ctrl+Alt+S), выбрать Tools->External Actions и добавить новое действие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Program должны быть строка

`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`.

В Arguments -

`https://www.google.com/search?q=wp-kama.ru+$SelectedText$&newwindow=1&hl=en`.

Обратите внимание, что внутри неё есть `$SelectedText$` - это макрос PhpStorm для вставки выделенного в редакторе текста в командную строку.

После сохранения External Tool команда доступна через меню Tools->External Tools. Но мы можем пойти дальше и вставить её во всплывающее меню редактора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь меню редактора по правой кнопке выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Инструкции для Windows, но для Mac или Linux процедуры выглядят аналогично.

Для использования браузера по умолчанию в Windows в Program должна быть строка

`rundll32`

а в Arguments -

`url.dll,FileProtocolHandler https://www.google.com/search?q=wp-kama.ru+$SelectedText$&newwindow=1&hl=en`